# Angular 5 code compiled in production mode gives void 0 not a function error

Tags: angular5

Runs fine in dev mode.

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (void 0) is not a function
    at main.aff8cee52d3bd3903f34.bundle.js:1
    at Object.cDNt (main.aff8cee52d3bd3903f34.bundle.js:1)
    at n (inline.0da255c51a7d5ae908f0.bundle.js:formatted:10)
    at Object.0 (main.aff8cee52d3bd3903f34.bundle.js:1)
    at n (inline.0da255c51a7d5ae908f0.bundle.js:formatted:10)
    at window.webpackJsonp (inline.0da255c51a7d5ae908f0.bundle.js:formatted:25)
    at main.aff8cee52d3bd3903f34.bundle.js:1
```

The bundle.js code where error occurs:

```
webpackJsonp([1], {
    ....
    wi = new yi.l("UseV4Plurals"), Ei = function() {}, Mi = function(e) {
        function t(t, n) {
            var r = e.call(this) || this;
            return r.locale = t,
                   r.deprecatedPluralFn = n,
                   r
        }
        return (void 0)(t, e),   <-------------- Error
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular-front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve",
      "build": "ng build",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "^5.0.5",
      "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.10-4905443",
      "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "gl-matrix": "^2.4.0",
      "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
      "three": "^0.88.0",
      "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "@angular/cli": "1.5.4",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
      "@types/gl-matrix": "^2.4.0",
      "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
      "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
      "@types/proj4": "^2.3.4",
      "@types/three": "^0.84.34",
      "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
      "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
      "karma": "~1.7.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
      "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
      "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
      "protractor": "~5.1.2",
      "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
      "tslint": "~5.7.0",
      "typescript": "~2.4.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your post to correctly format the code and exceptions. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. (I didn't do this by hand - the {} icon in the formatting toolbar does it for you on the selected text!)

Comment: Hi RRPitre  Did you find any solution for this.

Comment: Facing the same error with Angular 5.x using --prod. Anyone know of any work around or the root cause to this?

Comment: I was getting the same error. I was trying to build it with --prod and --aot flag.
When I decided to build without --aot, it worked. after that I again tried to build with --aot, this time it worked.

So try to include and exclude --aot flags couple of time. I don't know how but it worked for me.

Comment: got the same issue here, have you found out a workaround

Comment: Its pretty late to comment, but did you figure this out? I may have a solution for anybody who is still interested

Answer (score 3):

I have been experiencing the same issue. In addition to bmarti44's answer, I suggest running

`ng build --prod --source-map=true`

This helped us to diagnose where the error was coming from (an npm package in our case). We removed the package and production builds started working again. I appreciate this wont be an option for everyone.

---

For Reference, this is still an issue as of Angular 7

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this is the best answer, but if you're in a tough spot, you can disable the build optimizer on your prod build. Something like...

`ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false`

That "fixed" the issue and allowed us to build. I think that the build optimizer is removing a little too much code in certain instances, and breaking the codebase.

Comment: Just want to note, you should probably NOT do this long term... In our case, we were adding a library that was already minified (as @michael-hancook mentioned) , and when it was minified a second time, this error occurred. If you want to really fix the issue, you'll want to remove the offending lib from being minified by Angular.